# flutter: why property in flutter doc can't be identified in my program?

Tags: flutter, dart

when I'm working with flutter `CupertinoScrollbar` in [flutter doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoScrollbar-class.html), I found the property `thickness` and `thicknessWhileDragging`. But when I want to try the two properties my program just couldn't identify them. It showed a red wavy line and said `the named parameter isn't defined`. So why this happens? The related code is below.

```
CupertinoScrollbar(
                          isAlwaysShown: true,
                          controller: sc,
                          thickness: 3, // it said the named parameter isn't defined
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            controller: sc,
                            itemCount: 1,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(ScreenUtil.dp(22), 0, ScreenUtil.dp(23), ScreenUtil.dp(8.13)),
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Html(data: """$html""",),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`

if it still doesn't work, try close your code editor and then open it again

Comment: Thanks for your advice bro. I tried your solution but still the same. It's quite weird. Could you please tell me if you have the same situation when you use these properties in your program? Could it be a version issue?

Comment: i am not sure... But i have had it... I just close and reopen my VisualStudio Code, and then the problem is resolved